# How can I add a normal space between these components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styled-components

How can I add a normal space between these components?
I don't like the way of increasing the padding to the right,
I tried doing like this way by adding template strings ${``} but it did not work
Any suggestion on how to add a normal white space?

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:

**This is a bold span** normal span

```
index.js
<SpanWrapperBold>${`This is a bold span `}</SpanWrapperBold>
 <SpanWrapper>normal span</SpanWrapper>

SpanWrapper.js
export const SpanWrapperBold = styled.span`
  font-weight: bold;
`;

export const SpanWrapper = styled.span`
  padding: 3px;
`;
```

Comment: This should do it for you: `<SpanWrapperBold>This is a bold span</SpanWrapperBold>{" "}<SpanWrapper>normal span</SpanWrapper>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bold span {"\u00A0"}
normal span